# Slurm new worker nodes

Tags: cluster-computing, slurm, hpc

I want to build a cluster environment where nodes are automatically created and deleted. The jobs are to be distributed to the various nodes using Slurm.
Two questions:

- Is there an agent or similar for the Slurm workers so that the nodes automatically register with the head node?
- Is it possible to change the Slurm config file during runtime? (since new worker nodes could be added or deleted).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to restart the Slurm daemon for changes to the slurm.conf file to take effect, which could be problematic for jobs that are running. You may have errors (job failures or worse) if the Slurm control daemon finds that the slurm.conf is different due to checksum mismatch (see the official docs on adding nodes: https://slurm.schedmd.com/faq.html#add_nodes).